# Unable to parse Responce using json path Tester-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Unable to parse the response which contains "\",

```
{"Content":"[{\"SummaryID\":\"402014189352\",\"PeriodID\":\"3079\",\"PeriodName\":\"Q3 16\",\"SummaryData\":[{\"SummaryID\":\"402014189352\",\"Date\":\"11\/11\/2016\",\"RawMatrixData\":\"{\\\"LstEstimateInfo\\\":[{\\\"TemplateID\\\":402014189251,\\\"SummaryID\\\":402014189352,\\\"TemplateName\\\":\\\"Template_201611119\\\",\\\"TemplateDate\\\":\\\"11\/11\/2016 08:48:09\\\",\\\"SelfServe\\\":true}],\\\"LstPeriodList\\\":[{\\\"PeriodName\\\":\\\"Q1
```

Comment: your json is not correct, are you getting this type of response ?

Comment: please provide complete json response that you want to parse.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh yes iam getting this type of response, i want to parse Date from it

Comment: you can parse it but before parsing replace the "\" from the string and then using JSON parser you can parse try it.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh please give me details

Comment: are you working it in java ?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh no iam not using java, i used recording controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Regular Expression Extractor` and `BeanShell Post Processor`.

Steps As follows:

Add the following regex in the `Regular Expression Extractor` (to retrieve date value):

```
"Date\\":\\"(.*?)"
```

Add BeanShell Code as follows (to remove "\", in the first match):

```
String str1=vars.get("date_1").toString();
log.info("Before " + str1);
String temp = str1.replace("\\","");
log.info("After " + temp);
vars.put("date_formatted", temp);
```

Image references:
1. RegEx Extractor
[image]
2. BeanShell
[image]
3. View Results Tree
[image]

Comment: date object has multiple dates

Comment: change `match No.` value to `-1` to capture all the values. later, you can access them by `${date_1}`, `${date_2}` etc. update the BeanShell code by replacing `vars.get("date")` to `vars.get("date_1")` to fetch first match.

Comment: why i am getting this exception "error in method invocation java.lang.string is not found on class org.apache.log.logger"

Comment: please add the BeanShell code that you are using, to the question. The BeanShell code in the answer, working for me.

Comment: iam able to remove the forawrds slash, but when i pass to next post request ${date_1} then value is not getting transffered , showing error

Comment: After formatting the date, you have to save the new value into JMeter variable using `vars.put` method. then you access the new value using the key (mentioned in put method). `${date_1}` still refers to the date in the old format. please add BeanShell Code to the question, so can resolve the issue quickly. otherwise, it is trail and error.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1=vars.get("SummaryID").toString();
String str2=vars.get("TemplateID").toString();
log.info("Before " + str1);
log.info("Before " + str2);
java.lang.String temp = str1.replace("\\","");
java.lang.String temp1 = str2.replace("\\","");
log.info("After " + temp);
log.info("After " + temp1);
vars.put("date_format1", temp);
vars.put("date_format2", temp1);
```

Tried above code, remove "\", when i want to pass ${SummaryID_1} then post request doesnt works.

Comment: Resolved by adding ${date_format1} and ${date_format1}, in next post request